# How to pack image from HD into .exe file when building a final application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a c++ program that process some images and display results using namedWindow() (- > opencv).  I display 3 processed images and one image that is loaded from HD (in the same namedWIndow). SO when I run this program in VS2015 it works ok, but when I build .exe file and run applicaiton, it says that the parameter img (that stands for image from HD) is not passed...

How can I pack this image from HD to .exe file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual solution is not to pack it in the executable, but put the image (and other *resources*) in the same directory. That's why `C:\Program Files\` contains directories, and not executables.

Don't hardcode that directory name though, use `GetModuleFileName(nullptr, ...`